# How to Run different database query in ms access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have following code to run saved query and export data to excel report. 
How should I change the code if this query is in a different database?

```
DoCmd.Requery Q_Check_Mismatches
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export-Q_Check_Mismatches"
```

I know we can link all relevant tables to current database and then run the query locally. But I need this
because of DB size issue.

Appreciate your response

Cheers

Shabar

Comment: Have you considered "Compacting" the database to reduce its size? That may solve the issue

Comment: Yes Katana24, But still I am after this setup as I planned to access different DB when running query

Comment: have a look at this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-access/run-query-in-another-database/fba90dc9-606c-4938-b926-14c8bd3bc019

Comment: Thax Katana24. Appreciated

Comment: Following code worked for me                                      `Function QueryRun(strDBPath As String, strImportExport As String) ', _
'                        strQuery As String)
      
Dim objAccess As Access.Application

 Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  
 objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strDBPath
 objAccess.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport strImportExport

 objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
 objAccess.Quit
 
 Set objAccess = Nothing

End Function `

Comment: you should put this as your answer - would make it more readable plus you can mark it as your answer and help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me

```
Function QueryRun(strDBPath As String, strImportExport As String) 

Dim objAccess As Access.Application 

Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application") 
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase 

strDBPath objAccess.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport strImportExport 
objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase 
objAccess.Quit 
Set objAccess = Nothing 
End Function
```

Cheers

Shabar